# Firebase iOS -Cast StorageUploadTask Progress From Double to Int

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm uploading a video file to Firebase Storage and I'm using a progress Indicator to show it's progress. Everything works except I can't get it to display `Int`s (whole numbers), it's displaying `Doubles` like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The numbers should be whole numbers like `0%, 33%, and 96%`

I tried `casting` the percentLabel of type `Double` to `Int` but it kept crashing:

```
let percentComplete: Double = 100.0 * Double(completedUnitCount) / Double(totalUnitCount)
self?.progressLabel.text = "\(Int(percentComplete))%"
```

**How can I get these Doubles to become Ints?**

```
var uploadTask: StorageUploadTask?

uploadTask = videoIdRef?.putFile(from: videoUrl)

uploadTask?.observe(.progress, handler: {
    [weak self] (snapshot) in

    if let completedUnitCount = snapshot.progress?.completedUnitCount, let totalUnitCount =

        snapshot.progress?.totalUnitCount {

        let uploadProgress:Float = Float(completedUnitCount) / Float(totalUnitCount)
        self?.progressView.progress = uploadProgress   

        let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(completedUnitCount) / Double(totalUnitCount)
        self?.progressLabel.text = "\(percentComplete)%"
    }
})
```

Comment: try using `NumberFormatter` or `NSNumber` or yet simple `String(format: "%.0f", floor(double))`

Comment: @kathayatnk hey thanks it worked. I used self?.progressLabel.text = "\(String(format: "%.0f", floor(percentComplete)))%"

Comment: you should add that has the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Great , added the answer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use simple String initializer for this

```
String(format: "%.0f", floor(percentComplete))
```